# Simple example of "Spike-and-Slab Prior" for Bayesian Inference

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, bayesian

I would really like to understand how *Spike-and-Slab Priors* work in relation to *Linearized Models*. **Can somebody provide a toy example of a Spike-and-Slab Prior with a Bernoulli spike and a Gaussian slab?**

Here's my generic **Linear Model**:
$$ y = \mathbf{\beta*x} + \epsilon $$ or written as
$$ y = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\beta_j*x_j + \epsilon $$

I understand in **Bayesian Inference**, one has a **posterior distribution** that 
$$\mathbf{\theta} = [\beta_1, \beta_2, ..., \beta_j]$$
$$P(\theta|x) = \frac{P(x|\theta)*P(\theta)}{P(x)}$$

which is essentially *Likelihood* * *Prior* / *Normalizer*.

In this, each parameter (i.e. each $\beta_j$) has it's own distribution and I would like to *fit* the parameters ($\theta$) to the data ($x$) while the data is fixed and the parameters are random variables of their own distributions (btw, is that the same as $P(\theta_j)=P(x|\theta_j)*P(\theta_j)/P(x)$ with indicies?).

If any of this is incorrect, please correct me :) It would be greatly appreciated

**My reference:**

The paper I am reading uses **Bayesian Model Averaging** with a **Spike-and-Slab Prior**.  The Spike-and-Slab Prior uses "consists of a Bernoulli distribution that specifies whether or not a variable is selected as influential. The slab prior is a Gaussian distribution that models the effect sizes of the variables, conditional on their being chosen as influential" *Shankar et al. BMC Bioinformatics (2015) 16:31 DOI 10.1186/s12859-015-0467-6*.  To figure out what a **Spike-and-Slab Prior** was, so I can use this w/o any black-box `R` package, I checked out: https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall05/sta395/joelucas1.pdf where the description of the algorithm is below.

**My confusion:**

I don't understand how this is related to *Bernoulli* and *Gaussian* distributions.  Is the $h_{0j}$ a random variable following *Bernoulli* distribution and $h_{1j}$ following Gaussian ? If $f$ has to be extremely large, does the value of it matter and why does their need to be a separate value for every index $f_j$?  I found this resource on the stats stackexchange (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142818/is-a-spike-and-slab-prior-a-proper-prior) but I'm not sure what $F(x)$ is in the figure; it's definitely not a *p.d.f.* since it doesn't integrate to 1.

My apologies if this is long, but I've been looking up resources for over a week and it's explained a little differently everywhere I've looked; it's difficult to piece together the pieces w/o a toy example.

[image]